# HTML Entities in Stack Overflow Talent Job Posting Titles

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, stack-overflow-talent

Is it possible to use HTML entities in Talent Job posting titles?

I'd like to use a symbol now and then, and blank spaces for formatting. Nothing obnoxious, a single character to <strike>draw attention to</strike> *enhance* the post and spaces for formatting.

I've tried adding `&nbsp;` but the characters themselves are displayed. Are there any allowed entities?

**Examples**

- Trademark, Registered, Copyright symbols

  `ARDUINO &reg; Job Title
  company name`
- Preventing unwanted line wrapping between words

  `Job Title
  (some&nbsp;extra&nbsp;info here, on a 2nd line)
  company name`
- Currency Symbols

  `Job Title - &yen;50M/yr
  company name`
- Language-specific

  `&iquest;Te gusta React?
  company name`

Comment: _"Nothing obnoxious, a single character to draw attention"_ < I'd argue that using special characters to draw attention _is_ obnoxious.

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree with you, for the most part. 'Draw attention' was a bad choice of words. That said there are some entities that would be useful -
 currency symbols, fractions, trademark, etc.

Comment: It's probably for lack of imagination on my part, but can't think of an example of an actual use of these symbols or spaces in the title where it would be pertinent, useful, and not obnoxious. Maybe you can provide a couple of actual examples to defend the idea? Only the TM/CR symbols seem to be warranted, sometimes; but even those could be avoided for clarity (and correctly used in the body of the post)

Comment: @yivi - updated to include some examples

Comment: Me, I don't like the salary information in the title. We already have a salary field, don't we? Properly searchable and everything. And preventing line-breaks seem like a recipe to break the display of that title, somewhere/sometime. Of those examples, only the language specific entities are ok in _my_ book (although you could probably use UTF-8 characters and avoid the use meta-entity entirely).

Comment: So there's at least one use for entities. Should also refocus on the original question - if any HTML entities are allowed? The discussion has been derailed by opinions when the question was asking if something was possible.

Comment: Since you posted in meta; you had to known you were going to get community input. And the uses you are proposing for html-entities in the title are mostly seen as noise by some of the community; so we are not _derailing_ the discussion, but exploring the question to see if it makes sense; and informing it in case developers see your question as a FR.

Comment: Goods news is we got an answer -  HTML entities don't work. _AND_ they wouldn't be appreciated even if they did work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there is no support for HTML entities in job titles.

Besides, most of your examples don't belong in titles:

- Characters like ©, ® and ™ can be used in the job description, but they aren't really relevant in a job title. They're noise, distracting from what actually matters.
- Currency symbols aren't part of the job title either. There's a field to enter the salary.
- Non-breaking spaces aren't necessary. Long titles are truncated:

  > [image]
- I'm pretty sure characters like `&iquest;` can already be entered by just entering them in the field: `¿`, but you shouldn't want question / exclamation marks in your job posting's title.